# PHP PDO Camel Case

Tags: php, pdo, lint, camelcasing

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT p.id as ItemId FROM production p";

$pdo -> beginTransaction();
// PDO
try {
    $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_CASE, PDO::CASE_NATURAL );
    $result = $pdo->query($query);
    $test = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
?>
```

In the answer I get it lowercased:

```
[{"itemid":1},{"itemid":2}]
```

My Problem is I want in the response the keys also CamelCased. Already tried using CASE_Natural but it does not make any change.

Comment: `p.id as ItemId,` < that trailing comma is an issue. And `produdiction` stands to be misspelled.

Comment: what database you are using?

Comment: PostgresSql. And ty for the edit, I just wrote it fast as example.